# Expandable div (on click), inline-block, not push down other div's on second line

Tags: html, css

I have two lines with DIV's on each line. There are 3 div's on the first line. On the second line there are 2 div's, leaving the last column empty. Each div is set to inline-block so they can be next to each other.

The 3rd div on the first line has a collapsible link, that expands when clicked. The div becomes longer than the others on the same line.

When that div is expanded, it naturally pushes down the div's on the second line. I would like for the div's on the second line to not be pushed down. How can I achieve this?

Here is a drawing of what I would like to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Position them absolutely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the purpose of your code but you may want to divide them by columns and avoiding the negative margins, if that works for you, [**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3PUp9/3/):

**HTML**:

```
<div id="Column1">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block clear"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<div class="block big"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#Column1 {
    float: left;
}

.block {
    width: 50px;
    height: 80px;
    background: grey;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.big {
    height: 170px;
}
```

Or else, using negative margins ([**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bf9fp/3/)):

**HTML**:

```
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block big"></div>
<div class="block clear"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.block {
    width: 50px;
    height: 80px;
    background: grey;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.big {
    height: 170px;
    margin-bottom: -80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

contents getting pushed down here is normal

possible solution is taking off the extra space added by using negative margin

```
margin-bottom:-90px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ddtp9/1/

Comment: So the negative margin would have to come into effect only when that collapsible link is clicked?

Comment: you will have to use javascript or jquery to add and remove class when clicked